# R ggplot2 - Plot multiple functions in one plot with different x-axis ranges

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, limits

I want to draw different mathematical functions in one plot, restricting some of them to a different range of x-values. The code is:

```
# Different functions
stereographic <- function(theta,f=1) {
  2*f*tan(theta/2.0)
}

equidistant <- function(theta,f=1) {
  f*theta
}

equisolidangle <- function(theta,f=1) {
  2*f*sin(theta/2.0)
}

orthographic <- function(theta,f=1) {
  f*sin(theta)
}

# Plot
p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(0,pi)), mapping = aes(x = x))

p <- p +
  stat_function(fun=stereographic,aes(colour="Stereografisch")) +
  stat_function(fun=equidistant,aes(colour="Äquidistant")) +
  stat_function(fun=equisolidangle,aes(colour="Flächentreu")) +
  ylim(0,3)
print(p)
```

Now I want to add another function in the x-axis range [0,pi/2], but I cannot find a working method. I always get something like `ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval`. Is it possible to restrict `stat_function` to the new x-axis range or is there another good method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xlim` in `stat_function` allows you to set the range of x-values that are plotted:

```
new.func = function(theta,f=1) {
  f/sin(theta)
}

p + stat_function(fun=new.func, aes(colour="1/sin"), xlim=c(0,pi/2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Didn't know the `xlim` parameter because I forgot to update my packages.